# C# second form within first

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to be able to have two different forms in my application. One for users and one for production where settings etc. can be changed. I know I can use a password that when button is pressed will open the second form from within the first.

```
private void settingsButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Form2 settingsForm = new Form2();
  settingsForm.Show();
}
```

This would mean that a password would have to be entered each time to get into production mode which I don't want due to inconvenience. Is their any other method of doing this? Someone mentioned to me using a .ini file, but I have no experience of this.

This is what I have done working ok but when I close production form and try and open again nothing happens.

```
        private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Production.LOGGED == false)
        {
            MyEnterPassword = new EnterPassword("Please Enter Password to edit settings", "Edit Settings", "********");
            Application.DoEvents();
            if (MyEnterPassword.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Production newProdForm = new Production();
                newProdForm.Show();
            }
            Production.LOGGED = true;
        }
    }
```

and I have public static bool LOGGED = false; declared in the Production form

Comment: -1. You have made your question sound as if it is a UI-related issue you're facing; i.e. how to open one form inside another. But the title is very misleading. You're actually asking for suggestions about passwords and program configuration, which is a completely different matter.

Comment: @alexanderw and would I just call the new form if session != null

Comment: an .ini file? what is this 2004? well why not read it from tape as well

Comment: @KevinMoloney: What exactly is your question? (Please only ask one at a time.)

Comment: @WeylandYutani: The traditional Windows `.ini` file format is a bit limited, but conceptually, the idea of using a configuration file is sound. Lots of programs these days have configuration files of one sort or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a variable named LOGGED in your login form that will be opend like this  :

```
public static bool LOGGED=false;
```

and change your FOrmLoad code to this :

```
private void settingsButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 if(Form2.LOGGED==false){
     Form2 settingsForm = new Form2();
     settingsForm.Show();
 }
}
```

PS : after the login change its value to `true`

Comment: is that just after the if statement put LOGGED=true

Comment: no after the user tapes the password and you athentificate it put LOGGED=true;

Answer (score 0):

In your main program you need to store whether the user has already entered the password.

Define a boolean at the top of your main form `bool RequirePassword = true` Then when the user asks to open the serttings form

```
private void settingsButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(requirePassword)
    {
       //Request Password from user
       // When the password comes back from the form, check if it is valid
       // If it is, RequirePassword = false;
       // else post and error and return
    }

   Form2 settingsForm = new Form2();
   settingsForm.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save the password in form 1 and create a public string password on 2 form and send the password

```
private void settingsButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
Form2 settingsForm = new Form2();
settingsForm.Password = Form1PasswordString;
settingsForm.Show();
}
```

and on form 2 you will need
public string Password;